# Как определить содержит ли строка символы из Utf-8?

Tags: c#

Как мне определить имеет ли строка символы казахского алфавита.

Я сделал коллекцию символов представленных кодировкой Utf-8. И мне нужно теперь определить имеются ли эти символы в строке

```
public class KzLanguageIdentifier : ILanguageIdentifier
{
    private string[] _alphabet =
    {
        "U+04D8",
        "U+04D9",
        "U+0492",
        "U+0493",
        "U+049A",
        "U+049B",
        "U+04A2",
        "U+04A3",
        "U+04E8",
        "U+04E9",
        "U+04B0",
        "U+04B1",
        "U+04BA",
        "U+04BB",
        "U+04BA",
        "U+0456"
    };

    public bool CheckText(IEnumerable<string> text)
    {
        foreach (var line in text)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

UPD: Сделал вот так

```
public class KzLanguageIdentifier : ILanguageIdentifier
{
    private readonly char[] _alphabet =
    {
        'Ә',
        'ә',
        'Ғ',
        'ғ',
        'Қ',
        'қ',
        'Ң',
        'ң',
        'Ө',
        'ө',
        'Ұ',
        'ұ',
        'һ',
        'Һ',
        'і'
    };

    public bool CheckText(IEnumerable<string> text)
    {
        foreach (var line in text)
        {
            foreach (var letter in _alphabet)
            {
                if(line.Contains(letter))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: А в чём проблема использовать if или проблема в конвертировании?

Comment: @gfd2, я обновил вопрос, сделал пока самым простым способом

Comment: нормальный способ. Да, он "не быстрый" (квадратная сложность), но на небольших строках вполне-вполне. Можно за n*ln(n) сделать, но будет больше кода. Можно  в принципе и за линейное время сделать, если использовать хеш

Comment: @KoVadim, а как написать более оптимальный алгоритм?

Comment: Вот так сделайте: `text.Any(x => _alphabet.Contains(x));` и всё. Можно даже убрать интерфейс, и сделать статик класс. Изменить сигнатуру метода на static и передавать 2 аргумента: текст и массив.

Comment: я бы взял какой-либо хешмап, записал туда все символы, которые интересуют и пробегаясь по строке, проверял бы есть ли символ в хеше.  Так как символы алфавита скорее всего в ближайшее время меняться не будут, то в программе это может быть хеш, который один раз при старте инициируется.